# How to get the parent menu label of radiobutton?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to implement a 2-layer menu and press `Confirm` button to show its parent menu label and its value. Now I can get its value but have no idea how to get its parent menu label.

Please advise. Thank you.

```
import tkinter

def get_selection(menu, var):
  print('Menu: ' + menu.entrycget(0, "label"))  # How to get this ?
  print('Item: ' + var.get())

items = [['A', 'Apple', 'Amazon'], ['T', 'T-Mobile', 'Tesla']]
root = tkinter.Tk()
var = tkinter.StringVar(value='--')
menu_button = tkinter.Menubutton(
    root, textvariable=var, borderwidth=1, relief='raised')
main_menu = tkinter.Menu(menu_button, tearoff=False)
menu_button.configure(menu=main_menu)

for item in items:
  menu = tkinter.Menu(main_menu, tearoff=False)
  main_menu.add_cascade(label=item[0], menu=menu)
  for value in item[1:]:
    menu.add_radiobutton(value=value, label=value, variable=var)

menu_button.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, side=tkinter.TOP)
tkinter.Button(
    command=lambda: get_selection(menu, var),
    text='Confirm').pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, side=tkinter.BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Expected Output

```
# Case 1
Menu: A
Item: Apple

# Case 2
Menu: T
Item: Tesla
```

Actual Output

```
# Case 1
Menu: T-Mobile
Item: Apple

# Case 2
Menu: T-Mobile
Item: Tesla
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use same variable `menu` for all the cascade menu, so it finally refers to the last menu added.

You can use the text of the selected item to look up the required data in `items`:

```py
def get_selection(var):
    value = var.get()
    menu = ""
    for item in items:
        if value in item:
            menu = item[0]
            break
    print('Menu: ' + menu)
    print('Item: ' + value)

...

tkinter.Button(command=lambda: get_selection(var), text='Confirm').pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, side=tkinter.BOTTOM)
```